# git merge: filter files to avoid silly conflicts (like whitespace or case changes)

Tags: git, merge, whitespace, case-insensitive, conflict

I'm currently inside a very complicated merge in git, and I have many conflicts. The conflict is about two Ada source files.

I would like to make a merge that would ignore both whitespace changes and case changes (as the Ada language is case insensitive).
Do you know if there is a way to tell git to ignore some kind of changes before a merge ?

My solution is currently to run the GNAT pretty print on both branches before the merge, but if there was a common solution included in git, that would help me a lot.

Comment: It'd probably be easier to standardize internally case and whitespace anyway to avoid this problem _next_ merge; incidentally some tools such as xxdiff can make cleaning up merge conflicts a lot easier.

Comment: Note: git merge won't be bothered by case changes anymore, from git 2.0.1+: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978770/6309)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging without whitespace conflicts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776527/merging-without-whitespace-conflicts)

Answer (score 4):

from the [release notes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes/1.7.4.txt) of git 1.7.4:

> * The "recursive" strategy also learned to ignore various whitespace
>      changes; the most notable is -Xignore-space-at-eol.

I don't know if there is a strategy to ignore case changes though

Comment: See documentation: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.4/git-merge.html

Comment: This seems a good solution except for rebase and case change in Ada

Comment: @user: rebase should take strategy options as well – still not solving the case change case of course

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the case issue, which is problematic on case insensitive OS during a merge, this won't be an issue with git 2.0.1+ (June 25, 2014).

See [commit ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683) by [David Turner (`dturner-tw`)](https://github.com/dturner-tw)

#### [`merge-recursive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683/merge-recursive.c): fix case-changing merge bug

> On a case-insensitive filesystem, when merging, a file would be wrongly deleted from the working tree if an incoming commit had renamed it changing only its case.
>   When merging a rename, the file with the old name would be deleted -- but since the filesystem considers the old name to be the same as the new name, the new file would in fact be deleted.
>
> We avoid this by not deleting files that have a case-clone in the index at stage 0.

Comment: The question was more about case changes in file content itself. But that's still good information.