# Merging a gitbundle with tabs instead of spaces

Tags: git

I'm trying to merge a gitbundle into master which is several commits ahead of the bundle (see picture below for example). Problem is that the gitbundle commits all use tabs instead of spaces so git thinks the entire files have changed. If I were to simply merge the gitbundle into master then the last few commits to master would pretty much be gone.

What is the best way to resolve this problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCBGD.png

Comment: Perhaps merging into (or basing onto) an earlier, not whitespace-damaged commit, and then rebase the tip on top of that? I'd experiment on a copy of the repository, and probably there in special branches, until you get what you want.

Comment: I think this is the answer you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262473/53936

Comment: Thanks, JosefAssad. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262473/53936 did work for me (mostly).