# Get newline changes from another branch without manually merging

Tags: git, merge, newline

I'm trying to bring commits from `master` which fixed a ton of newline issues into a feature branch without having to manually deal with all the conflicts induced by those newline changes.

We made a few commits in the `master` branch to fix some messed up newline characters.
These commits touched many files in the repository.
Now I'd like to bring those changes into a feature branch `myfeature` which has its own commits apart from what exist in master. If we just do

```
$ git checkout myfeature
$ git merge master
```

we get conflicts because Git thinks that every line in master is different from every line in `myfeature`, which is true. If we try to use

```
$ git merge -s recursive -Xignore-space-at-eol master
```

as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256769/git-merge-and-fixing-mixed-spaces-and-tabs-with-two-branches/5262473#5262473), Git will use the newlines from `myfeature` for any line where there were no substantial changes in `master`, which is the opposite from what I want.

Is there a way to merge `master` into `myfeature` getting the updated newlines but without having to manage conflicts manually?

Comment: why don’t you just merge the other direction if the command then does what you want?

Comment: @Chronial: Merging the other direction puts unfinished work from `myfeature` into `master`, which is definitely no bueno.

Answer (score 1):

More a comment, but too long: Just merge the other direction and name the branches the way you like it:

```
git branch tmpbranch master
git checkout tmpbranch
git merge -s recursive -Xignore-space-at-eol -m "my merge message" myfeature
git branch -f myfeature tmpbranch
git checkout myfeature
git branch -D tmpbranch
```

Note that git records the direction of the merge, which will be incorrect after this. But I have never seen a tool actually use that information and people constantly mess this up anyways, so this shouldn’t be problem.

Comment: This is definitely a simple and probably good enough approach. I'll try this tomorrow at work and see if it works nice. Thanks.

Comment: I wound up making a series of blunders and screwing everything up. I haven't forgotten about this post though. Since I owe it to the Universe to evaluate this method carefully I'll mock up the situation and try it.

Comment: Do you have the branch names reversed in the first line of code?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I do the merge I get the fixed newlines only in files which have not been changed in the feature branch.