# --ignore-all-space for EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-diff

I am using EGit(3.4.1.201406201815-r) with Eclipse (Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)).

When I try to merge a branch from the remote repository with my local repository I get a lot of conflicting files. 
The differences in these files are mainly caused by differences in the number of whitespaces or number of empty lines. I would like to ignore these.

For example I will get::

```
<<< Head
4Whitespaces CR LF
==========
3Whitespaces CR LF
>>>> branch name
```

My goal for now is to ignore any kind of white spaces (white spaces, empty lines, line breaks, tabs, indents, etc.).

I already set these Preferences:

- Preferences/General/Compare/Patch ignore white space
- Preferences/General/New text file line delimiter --> default(Windows)
- Team/Git/Configuration User Settings: core.autocrlf = false
- Team/Git/Configuration User Settings: core.whitespace= blank-at-eol, blank-at-eof, space-before-tab, cr-at-eol

I saw that [one could use the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784089/1503237)

```
  git merge -Xignore-all-space
```

Is there a possibility to use this in Egit as well?