# Weird git diff log (exactly whitespace) in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, git-diff, xcode13

**Xcode13, macOS Monterey 12.0 (beta)**

Hi, I have a weird whitespace error in the git diff log. 
Happened in Xcode13 (or Monterey Beta), And never before.

Please see below two pictures.

- first one: in My IDE
- another one: in pull request

Has anyone come across this issue?
Or is there a way to get it to come out like before?

[image: ide]

[image: pr]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if this is because of a contributor using a different tab size in their code.

If merging such pull request is not practical on GitHub itself, you might consider:

- [checking out the PR locally](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally)
- merging the PR branch yourself, [ignoring any whitespace conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784089/6309), and re-applying your own code formatting standards.